# Chrome not recognizing function arguments correctly

Tags: javascript, events

I have wrote some cross browser code for adding event listeners, then chrome started being funky, anyone know why this is happening?

Add Event listener code:

```
function addEventListener(Elm,Type,Func)
{
    if(Elm.attachEvent)
        Elm.attachEvent((Type.substr(0,2) == 'on' ? Type : 'on'+Type),Func);
    else
        Elm.addEventListener(Type,Func);
}
```

Code calling the method:

```
addEventListener(window,'load',SetSize);
addEventListener(window,'resize',SetSize);
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object load has no method 'addEventListener'
```

You can very clearly see that I have passed the arguments in the correct order yet they are not interpreted in said order..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have overwritten `window.addEventListener`.

The native signature is: `event_name, callback` but yours is: `object, event_name, callback`.

Change the name of your function `addEventListener` or namespace it, like `my_framework.addEventListener`

Comment: Yup that was it, thankyou. Never know anything globally defined belonged to window.

Comment: It's actually `event_name, callback, useCapture`, if you leave out `useCapture` it will not even work in Firefox < 6

Answer (score 3):

You have redefined `window.addEventListener`. Anything you declare in the global namespace basically belongs to `window`, so:

```
function addEventListener(...) {

}
```

is the same as:

```
window.addEventListener = function(...) {

}
```

The argument signature for the native `addEventListener` is `eventName`, `listener`, but you have `Elm`, `Type`, `Func`.

Then inside your function body, you are doing `Elm.addEventListener` and passing it `'load'` and `SetSize`. In that call, it calls *your* function again (because `Elm` is `window`) and this time, it attempts to call `addEventListener` on the string `'load'`, which won't work because a string doesn't have that method.

Change the name of your function, or namespace it, and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the window object has not .attachEvent or .addEventListener.

This may caused because your function is named addEventListener and has overwritten the window.addEventListener()